Issues with default properties when using custom properties Tailwind
I am using Tailwind on the project and I have encountered a problem when writing custom properties.
The problem is when using rounded-lg, rounded-xl, rounded-2xl and ext. If I use the basic configuration there are no problems. If I add at least one configuration to borderRadius. I will get an error.
Base config
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {},
  plugins: [],
}

Custom config
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    borderRadius: {
      'sm-6-vw': '7.5vw',
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}

Error

Using in App.css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
    .gor-scroll {
        @apply rounded-2xl
    }
}

import main file
import './App.css'

If you don't use in @apply then the main error will go away. And if you then write rounded-2xl in the component itself then the class will not be applied.

As per the documentation (emphasis mine):

To override an option in the default theme, add your overrides directly under the theme section of your tailwind.config.js:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    // Replaces all of the default `opacity` values
    opacity: {
      '0': '0',
      '20': '0.2',
      '40': '0.4',
      '60': '0.6',
      '80': '0.8',
      '100': '1',
    }
  }
}

This will completely replace Tailwind’s default configuration for that key, so in the example above none of the default opacity utilities would be generated.

Thus, applied to your example, none of the default rounded-* classes would exist, only your rounded-sm-6-vw would exist, hence the error.
If you want to preserve the default values as well as adding your own, you'd define your values under theme.extend:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      borderRadius: {
        'sm-6-vw': '7.5vw',

As per the documentation:

If you’d like to preserve the default values for a theme option but also add new values, add your extensions under the theme.extend key in your configuration file. Values under this key are merged with existing theme values and automatically become available as new classes that you can use.

